# Vote up for tag synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I've been looking around on SO to see when to vote on tag synonyms, but I cannot find the answer.

I was trying to vote up for [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) and [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) as synonym.
But it did not take my vote.

Could anyone of you help me out?

Comment: You need 2500 reputation to vote on tag synonyms, see the [privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) (Titled *Suggest **and vote** on tag synonyms*)

Comment: @Sha, funny, does that mean the synonym page is misleading? It says "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. **Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.**" To me it implies that rep is needed for suggesting, but not for voting.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall true, looks like the privilege page need to be rephrased then..

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall OK, edited what I can on the [privilege page here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) it will be pushed within day or so to all sites, and asked to [change the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/please-change-title-of-create-tag-synonyms-privilege) in there as well.

Comment: Good thing nobody asks any questions about GPRS Access Point Names…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately (or furtunately, who knows), one needs to have a total answer score of 5 or more on a specific tag to be able to vote for the synonym. Here "total answer score" is total upvotes minus total downvotes. From your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713824/robuust?tab=tags&sort=name) I can see that you have not answered any questions on the [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) tag, thus you can't vote.

However, it should show a notification about that for you, like this:

[image]

Comment: Yep, even 20K+ users can't vote without enough score on the specific tag. The system works! :)