# Please change title of "create tag synonyms" privilege page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, privileges-page

The title of the [create tag synonyms privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) is currently:

> Suggest and vote on tag synonyms

This is misleading, since **voting** on a synonym requires only net score of 5 or more on the tag.

Can this be changed to something like:

> Suggest tag synonyms

Or to be consistent with the privileges menu:

> Create tag synonyms

Answer (score 5):

The title has since been changed to "[Create Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)".

[image: Create Tag Synonyms]

Comment: Amusingly, the page URL still reflects the original title, `suggest-tag-synonyms`.